# Create Rundeck Environment Project Variables using user interface

Tags: rundeck

I am using Powershell script to run some jobs in remote server.
I created a Project(ProjectTest), there are around 10 jobs inside this project.
All 10 jobs share few variables. e.g Server Endpoint. Using UI how can create variables which can be accessed by powershell script in all jobs.

Answer (score 1):

To do that via GUI go to Project Settings -> Edit Configuration -> Edit Configuration File (the up to right [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kstmW.jpg)) and add the global variable on textbox like `project.globals.X=BMW`, save, and you can use that value on any project for example on your script step (PowerShell): `Write-Host "Value: @globals.X@"`.

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#global-execution-variables).

Comment: how can i add passwords

Comment: The best approach to use passwords is to use the Rundeck Key Storage (https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/key-storage.html#rundeck-key-storage), for example, you can add a  password there and create a secure option referencing your password saved on your key storage (and use it on your project as an option, take a look at this https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#secure-options).

Comment: This link is more useful: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#secure-options-using-key-storage